# How to use OneDrive CSharp SDK as a Service or daemon app?

Tags: c#, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I am coding against the `OneDrive C# SDK`and I have a few questions.

Question 1.

Does the `OneDrive C# SDK` use the `Microsoft Graph API` under the hood?

... If so, how can I use the `SDK` to pass in my `client_Id` and `client_secret` and authenticate as a service or daemon app instead of a traditional OAuth for a user?

I have proofed out the authentication for a service with `REST` calls but I am trying to proof out if it is still possible to use a `C# SDK` instead.

Question 2.

I found this article [Azure Active Directory Graph Service Tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2013/01/23/walk-through-for-building-a-net-application-for-accessing-windows-azure-active-directory-graph-service/). After following the example I am able to create an `HTTP POST` call and return an `access_token`. My question is there a way to use this token in conjunction with the `Microsoft Graph CSharp SDK` or `OneDrive CSharp SDK` to serve as the authentication process?

**Update:**

Okay, I was able to proof out some more and having a working code, but I am now getting an error around `{Code: InvalidAuthenticationTokenMessage: Access token validation failure.`

I did the exact same call with `Postman` and was able to get data back with `REST` calls, is `REST` the only way to achieve this?

I created a gist for my attempt: [Code](https://gist.github.com/jaycdave88/dc8ec99467e43ea8ee54d4ba5252d210)

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

On line 62 in the gist, I was hitting the wrong resource. The correct resource is `https://graph.microsoft.com`

Comment: Thanks for following up with your solution!